# Bug: Moderator not getting the mod tag but being tagged as a bot in mod actions for comments

Tags: bug, comments, community-user

This happened [on this post's deleted comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1178797/ln-failed-to-create-symbolic-link-function-not-implemented/1377300#comment2372475_1377300) - visible to moderators and staff as it's a deleted comment:

[image]

This is a post done by a reviewer and masked by the Community bot.

Mitch is an actual diamond moderator, not a bot, this is a problem with the system not properly tagging things correctly for users.

Comment: Do we know if Mitch has passed any CAPTCHA tests recently? :P

Comment: So that [makes them two](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59335841#59335841)!

Comment: Related on MSE: ["Bot" label appears next to my username when I delete a comment posted by the Community bot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372412)